# How can I use the function 'begin atomic' in my sql code to create a trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

**My code**

```
 delimiter //
 create table NumAppApk as select count(distinct App_Name) as AppNum, count(ID) as ApkNum 
 from market_app_metadata;

 create trigger numCounter before insert on market_app_metadata
 for each row
 begin
     set @tmp = (select count(*) from market_app_metadata where App_Name = new.App_Name);
     update NumAppApk set ApkNum = ApkNum + 1;
     if @tmp < 1 then
         update NumAppApk set AppNum = AppNum + 1;
     end if;
 end;
 //
```

---

**Some definitions and purpose**

1. market_app_metadata

   This table includes columns : `App_Name` which means the true name of an app, `Package_Name` which means the name of the package of an apk. So cases are that different versions of the same apk have different apks.
2. **NumAppApk**

   So this table is set to count how many apps and apks are there in the `market_app_metadata` table. But since the table is updating all the time, so I want to use `mysql trigger` to query the real-time data quickly from table `NumAppApk`

---

**Difficulty**

To count the **distinct** count of `App_Name`, every time there exists a new row, I use

```
set @tmp = (select count(*) from market_app_metadata where App_Name = new.App_Name);
```

to count how many apps in the table has the same name with this new one.

So if `@tmp == 0`, this means the new row represents a new app.

I can not find the logic mistake of my way, but **the result is wrong**

[image: The wrong result]

It turns out like the conditional statement `if @tmp < 1 then` doesn't works, or maybe I think I should use `begin atomic` to make sure the atomicity.

---

**To conclude -- Two questions**

- Is there any logic mistake in my code ?
- How can I use `begin atomic` in MySQL Server 5.7.18? (This statement will cause error `mysql - ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax ...`.)

Comment: Update statement without a where clause will update all records which is probably not what you want.

Comment: There is only one line in the table `NumAppApk`, and what I want to update is just this one line, so I think the statement without a where clause is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your logic is wrong or that the code is wrong here's why

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> /*
   /*> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS market_app_metadata;
   /*> CREATE TABLE market_app_metadata( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, APP_NAME VARCHAR(10));
   /*> create table numappapk (id int default 1,appnum int,apknum int);
   /*> */
MariaDB [sandbox]> TRUNCATE TABLE OCCURSRESULTS;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> truncate table market_app_metadata;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists numappapk;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO market_app_metadata(APP_NAME) VALUES ('AAA'),('BBB'),('AAA');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table NumAppApk as select count(distinct App_Name) as AppNum, count(ID) as ApkNum
    ->  from market_app_metadata;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.28 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM NUMAPPAPK;
+--------+--------+
| AppNum | ApkNum |
+--------+--------+
|      2 |      3 |
+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Numappapk is as I expect.

If we then create the trigger

```
 DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS numcounter;
 delimiter //
 #create table NumAppApk as select count(distinct App_Name) as AppNum, count(ID) as ApkNum 
 #from market_app_metadata;

 create trigger numcounter before insert on market_app_metadata
 for each row
 begin
    insert into occursresults(msg) values ('start');
     #set tmp = IFNULL((select count(*) from market_app_metadata where App_Name = new.App_Name),0);
     set @tmp = (select count(*) from market_app_metadata where App_Name = new.App_Name);
     insert into occursresults(msg) values (concat('tmp:', ifnull(@tmp,'null'),' newappname:', ifnull(new.app_name,'newapp is null')));
     #select appnum,apknum into _appnum,_apknum from NumAppApk;

     set @appnum = (select appnum from NumAppApk);
     set @apknum = (select apknum from NumAppApk);
      insert into occursresults(msg) values (concat(' before update apknum appnum:',ifnull(@appnum,0),' apknum:',ifnull(@apknum,0)));
     update NumAppApk set ApkNum = ApkNum + 1;
     if @tmp < 1 then
            insert into occursresults(msg) values (concat(ifnull(new.app_name,'newapp is null'), ' tmp < 1'));
         update NumAppApk set AppNum = AppNum + 1;
     end if;
 end  //

 DELIMITER ;
```

Note the occursresults table is for debug purposes

And we then do this

```
INSERT INTO market_app_metadata(APP_NAME) VALUES ('CCC'),('AAA');
select * from market_app_metadata;
select count(distinct app_name) from market_app_metadata;
SELECT * FROM NUMAPPAPK;
select * from occursresults;
```

we get this

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from market_app_metadata;
+----+----------+
| ID | APP_NAME |
+----+----------+
|  1 | AAA      |
|  2 | BBB      |
|  3 | AAA      |
|  4 | CCC      |
|  5 | AAA      |
+----+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select count(distinct app_name) from market_app_metadata;
+--------------------------+
| count(distinct app_name) |
+--------------------------+
|                        3 |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM NUMAPPAPK;
+--------+--------+
| AppNum | ApkNum |
+--------+--------+
|      3 |      5 |
+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from occursresults;
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| id | msg                                     |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
|  1 | start                                   |
|  2 | tmp:0 newappname:CCC                    |
|  3 |  before update apknum appnum:2 apknum:3 |
|  4 | CCC tmp < 1                             |
|  5 | start                                   |
|  6 | tmp:2 newappname:AAA                    |
|  7 |  before update apknum appnum:3 apknum:4 |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Numappapk is as I expect and occursresults shows that the if tmp < 1 code is being executed for 'CCC'.

Please have a look and comment if the model I have used is not consistent with yours or the end result is not as you would expect from my model.

Comment: Thank you for your explicit sample and experiment, at last I find out the problem is that when I insert some lines into the database (using python),it seems that it will first write some columns and then update the other columns, and that results in my mistake. Thanks for your answer~